# Too many variables in Java?

Tags: java, oop

I'm still fairly new to Java, but I personally feel my code is sloppy, having way too many variables. I know I could hide them in methods or classes, but I heard that putting them in a separate class is bad practice and most of them aren't static. Can anyone give me some tips? Thanks in advance!

```
public static float c = .2f; //cube dimensions
private float separation = 4.0f*c;
private float angle = 0f; //set to 0
private float rotate = 1.0f;
private float h_height = 1.0f;
private float h_width = 1.0f;
private float h_length = 1.0f;
private float b_height = 1.5f;
private float b_width = .5f;
private float b_length = 1.0f;
private float a_height = 1.5f;
private float a_width = .5f;
private float a_length = .5f;
private float l_height = 1.5f;
private float l_width = .5f;
private float l_length = .5f;
private float h_x_s = 0.0f*c;
private float h_y_s = 5.0f*c;
private float h_z_s = 0.0f*c;
private float h_x;
private float h_y;
private float h_z;
private float b_x_s = 0.0f*c;
private float b_y_s = 2.5f*c;
private float b_z_s = 0.0f*c;
private float b_x;
private float b_y;
private float b_z;
private float a_x_s = 1.5f*c;
private float a_y_s = 2.5f*c;
private float a_z_s = .0f*c;
private float a_x;
private float a_y;
private float a_z;
private float l_x_s = .5f*c;
private float l_y_s = -.5f*c;
private float l_z_s = 0.0f*c;
private float l_x;
private float l_y;
private float l_z;
private float a_rotate = 0f;
private float a_speed = .6f;
private float l_rotate = 0;
private float l_speed = .6f;
private double a_c;
private double l_c;
private double a_s;
private double l_s;
private float max_a = 30f; //angle
private float max_l = 30f; //angle
private boolean a_forward;
private boolean l_forward;
private float move_z = 0; //set to 0
private float speed_z = .01f*separation;
private float max_z = 2*separation;
private boolean forward_z;
```

P.S. The comments aren't actually what the variables are for, just reminders to me while debugging. Also, my variable names will probably meet much disapproval from professional developers, but it's something I can keep track of easily. And like I said before, the majority of these variables are actively changing, and used in multiple methods for that matter, but a few I'm away I can hide away.

Comment: Where did you hear putting them in separate classes was bad?

Comment: Looks like you should create some classes.  Creating your own classes is one of the most fundamental and powerful concepts in object oriented programming.

Comment: `but I heard that putting them in a separate class is bad practice and most of them aren't static`. That is the trouble of using your ears, that you listen things like that. If it makes sense for a separate class (from the current class), please use it. And please, document its meaning.

Comment: Without knowing what the purpose of your app is or anything about what you are trying to achieve, it is not possible to offer good suggestions regarding design.  At this point, only you know your design goals.

Comment: @scottb - However... the prefixes he's using on his variable names (and the acutal names of the variables) make it quite clear that he can benefit from some classes.  For example, it looks like he should have one class that has three fieds: _length_, _width_, _height_, another class with three fields: _x_, _y_, _z_, anoterh with two fields: _rotate_, and _speed_, etc....

Comment: @jahroy: Of course.  It's Java.  You can never have too many classes.  But looking at all those floats tells me too little about the data he's trying to represent or how it ought to be organized into classes.  It's a list of floats without much context.  To me, this means that he doesn't know enough about object-orientation to even get started.  The java tutorials is probably the next best step.

Comment: Fair enough... Technically you're right, but I think we can tell what's going on.  The OP should **definitely** use variable names that are **WAY** more descriptive!!!!

Comment: There is a special [CodeReview StackExchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site dedicated to reviewing code and practices.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your variables are *screaming* for you to put them in classes.

I'm just inferring based on your variable names, but I'm almost certain that's what you need.

For example, you might implement 3 classes like the ones at the bottom of this answer.

This would allow your variable declarations to look something like this:

**Variable declarations:**

```
Polygon polygonA = new Polygon(1.5, .5, .5);
Polygon polygonB = new Polygon(1.5, .5, 1.0);
Polygon polygonL = new Polygon(1.5, .5, .5);

Coordinate coordH = new Coordinate();
Coordinate coordB = new Coordinate();

Transform transformA = new Transform(0, .6);
Transform transformL = new Transform(0, .6);
```

**Example class definitions:** (each of these goes in a separate file)

```
class Polygon {

    float height;
    float width;
    float length;

    public Polygon(int h, int w, int l) {
        height = h;
        width = w;
        length = l;
    }
}

class Coordinate {

    float x; 
    float y;

    public Coordinate() {}

    public Coordinate(float xCoord, float yCoord) {
        x = xCoord;
        y = yCoord;
    }
}

class Transform {

    float rotate;
    float speed;

    public Transform(float r, float s) {
        rotate = r;
        speed = s;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, but while I agree with the more-OO approach you present, its application remains subjective.  If the classes are only being used in the one class in the question, defining numerous classes like these can make a project unnecessarily bulky.

Comment: And on another note, I wouldn't define an object that has three-dimensional size a polygon, as a polygon is simply a shape formed from a series of points. I find a name such as `Dimension3D` or similar to be more clear in describing the class' intent.

Comment: Sure... You can always make that argument.  But I would say there's little question that _some_ kind of classes will always be better than tons of separate variables that are only related by their names.

Comment: I don't see much point in nit-picking the class names I chose... My goal was to whip up a quick example to demonstrate a point.  There's a very good chance that the class names I chose are horrible (and that should be irrelevant for this exercise).  The OP can choose whatever names he wants.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure where you got the idea that it is *not done* to put variables in separate classes. I don't know the intent of your code, but I guess it has something to do with cubes.

You seem to have four types of variables: `h`, `b`, `a` and `l`, and they are *very* similar. You *should* abstract them into a class. Something like this:

```
public class Cube
{
    private float height;
    private float width;
    private float length;

    private float x_s;
    private float y_s;
    private float z_s;

    private float x;
    private float y;
    private float z;

    // Add getters, setters, constructors, etc...
}
```

And then you can reduce your current code to:

```
private Cube h;
private Cube b;
private Cube a;
private Cube l;
```

Quite neat, right?

And you could further abstract the coordinates and sizes into a `Vector3` object:

```
public class Vector3
{
    private float x;
    private float y;
    private float z;
}
```

Making your `Cube`:

```
public class Cube
{
    private Vector3 size;
    private Vector3 position_s;
    private Vector3 position;
}
```

Or, if size and position are really different things, you could even make a `Point` class for the X, Y, Z coordinates, and a `Size` class for the `height`, `length`, `width` values.

By the way, you *really* should use meaningfull variable names. Things like `h`, `a`, `b`, `l` and `x_s` don't mean anything to me. And if you look at your code after some time, it won't mean anything to you either.

Comment: Great answer.  **Please** use meaningful variables names!!!!

Comment: +1 for all the times I went back to old code and had no idea what the hell my variable names meant. -_-